# How should I be reading Census API data into R

Tags: r, json, api, readr

I am working to read Census data into R using the agency's API, but I'm struggling to get it to read in the right format.

The URL that I'm trying to read in: https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/eits/mwts?get=data_type_code,time_slot_id,seasonally_adj,category_code,cell_value,error_data&time=2012

And the format of that data if you just look at it in the web browser:

[image]

The closest I've gotten is with this series of code:

```
library(jsonlite)
data <- url("https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/eits/mwts? get=data_type_code,time_slot_id,seasonally_adj,category_code,cell_value,error_data&time=2012")
    
    
datanew <- fromJSON(data)
```

But as you can see that's still not in a good dataframe format.

[image]

Is there an easier way that I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but that API returns an improper use of JSON. Anyway, you can coerce `datanew` to a data frame, but that leaves you with the column labels in row 1. So you use row 1 to name the columns then remove row 1.

```
df <- as.data.frame(datanew)
names(df) <- df[1, ]
df <- df[-1, ]
```

After which you propably want to cast each column to appropriate data types.